# Platfrom hooks not found when deploying to AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to deploy a django app to elastic beanstalk. This worked well initially but I have recently made a change to the database models and so need to migrate these in the production environment.

Looking at old logs I can see there was not a problem with this previously, but now the migrate command is not found:

```
2022/05/23 07:45:34.726621 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2022/05/23 07:45:34.726634 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/postdeploy/
2022/05/23 07:45:34.726654 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist
```

I am deploying using  `eb deploy` and I the path `mywebsite/.platfrom/hooks/postdeploy/01_migrate.sh` exists. Does anyone know why it is not being found?

Comment: It can find the hooks if I move the .platform directory up on level, however ti was working previously with other folder structure, is there a setting that tells aws where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/var/app/current/.platform/hooks/postdeploy
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.